# Is the Nand2Tetris Hack computer's RAM a good model for how RAM is structured on x86 machines?

Tags: memory, nand2tetris

The following is the structure of RAM for the entire Hack Computer in Nand2Tetris:

[image]

Putting aside virtual memory, is this a good simplified model for how the entire RAM is set up on x86 computers? Is RAM really just made of clusters of memory regions each with their own stack, heap and instruction memory, stacked on top of each other in RAM?

Basically, is RAM just a collection of independent and separate memory regions of each process/program running? Or, does RAM consist of variables scattered randomly from different programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hugely over-simplified, processes on a machine with Virtual Memory could all *think* they have a memory map similar to that of the Hack Virtual Machine (note: Virtual Memory != Virtual Machine).

However, individual chunks of each process' memory map might be mapped to some arbitrary physical memory, shuffled off to a swap file, not allocated until actually needed, shared with other processes, and more. And those chunks that are in RAM might be anywhere (and might move).

You may find this article to be a good starting point to understanding Virtual Memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory